# EF Many to Many - 3 way

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I have these 3 entities:

- User
- Account
- Permission

A user has many accounts, and an account can belong to many users.
Plus, an `UserAccount` can have many permissions and a permission can belong to many `UserAccount`s.

I was thinking having the `User` being an AggregateRoot for everything. So I could only see `Accounts` through a `User` and `Permissions` through the `Account` of a user.

But I am having some difficulty getting all together. Not sure If I try to make the entities for each of the join tables or if I let EF take care of it (and how) through `hasmany` `withmany`.

I'm pretty sure I will have in the end the following join tables: `UserAccount` and `UserAccountPermission`. But I'm struggling getting to work.

Can someone help me with model creation and entities needed?

Comment: show what you have done so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According your description, this is the model that would work for you:

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<UserAccount> UserAccounts { get; set; }
}

public class Account
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<UserAccount> UserAccounts { get; set; }
}

public class UserAccount
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    public virtual Account Account { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Permission> Permissions { get; set; }
}

public class Permission
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<UserAccount> UserAccounts { get; set; }
}

public class AuthorizationDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Account> Accounts { get; set; }
    public DbSet<UserAccount> UserAccounts { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Permission> Permissions { get; set; }
}
```

In this case, EF will create **many-to-many** relationship model `UserAccountPermission` (`UserAccount` <-> `Permission`) for you but you cannot access it directly

Now, if you need to get access to it, you have to add it explicitly to your model (similar than `UserAccount`):

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<UserAccount> UserAccounts { get; set; }
}

public class Account
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<UserAccount> UserAccounts { get; set; }
}

public class UserAccount
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    public virtual Account Account { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<UserAccountPermission> Permissions { get; set; }
}

public class Permission
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<UserAccountPermission> UserAccounts { get; set; }
}

public class UserAccountPermission
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual UserAccount UserAccount { get; set; }
    public virtual Permission Permission { get; set; }
}

public class AuthorizationDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Account> Accounts { get; set; }
    public DbSet<UserAccount> UserAccounts { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Permission> Permissions { get; set; }
    public DbSet<UserAccountPermission> UserAccountPermissions { get; set; }
}
```

With this you should have all your scenarios covered

Comment: This was the solution with a small change as I'm using IEntityTypeConfiguration to config my entities. And used 
"builder.HasMany(p => p.UserAccounts).WithMany(ua => ua.Permissions);"
To get joint table.